# Android MessageQueue nativePollOnce

Tags: android

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 768x6528 max size 8192 color type 4 has context 1
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce()(MessageQueue.java:-2)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next()(MessageQueue.java:326)

```html
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 768x6528 max size 8192 color type 4 has context 1
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce()(MessageQueue.java:-2)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next()(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop()(Looper.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main()(ActivityThread.java:7094)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

```
at android.os.Looper.loop()(Looper.java:181)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main()(ActivityThread.java:7094)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()(Method.java:-2)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```